# chmod result "No such file or directory"

Tags: chmod

I'm trying to install this program with the instructions provided here: https://bitbucket.org/2E0PGS/vk-album-downloader/src/master/.

Here are the steps involved from that link:

```
1. Clone Repo

2. Make the file executable: chmod +x VK_Album_Downloader.sh

3. Run the program ./VK_Album_Downloader.sh <Album URL>
```

I was able to clone but have not made the file executable since I get the return, "No such file or directory."

I'm relatively new to this and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Assuming you use ```git clone```, do you ```cd``` into the downloaded directory?

Comment: @ClaytonL oof...my only defense is I'm an idiot doofenshmirtz. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.